# show and hide list items on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list looking like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="pop">
     <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 6</li>
          <li>Item 7</li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div id="info-1></div>
<div id="info-2></div>
```

And when you hover over one of the items a window is displayed with some info regarding the item. I have worked this out for one item, now I wanna know how I can make this work for the entire list.

My initial thought was to create one script per each item... but that seems a bit thick considering the functionality of js.

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
     $('pop a').hover(function(){
          $('#info-1').show();
     },function(){
          $('#info-1').hide();
     });
});
```

So my question is of course, how can I make this script to work for all items.

Comment: In future, please try to indent your code; it makes it more readable. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've binded an hover event on all `a` tags inside pop element (though you have syntax error, you should always add '#' when addressing an element by id)  and you don't have them
what you''re looking for is :

```
$('#pop li').hover(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#pop li').hover(
    function() {
        $('div.info').eq($(this).index()).show();
    }, function() {
        $('div.info').eq($(this).index()).hide();
    });​
```

Working with slightly-changed HTML:

```
<div id="pop">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nJm5J/).

What I forgot to say is that this will show the `.info` element that corresponds to the same `index` as the currently hovered-over `li` element, so hovering the *first* `li` will show the first `.info`, and so on. So it's dependant on maintaining a predictable relationship between the `li` and the `.info` elements.

As an aside, it's possible to replicate this interaction using just CSS, albeit it requires a *click* rather than a hover event, so long as you amend the `li` HTML to include a link that points to the `id` of the relevant `div`:

```
<div id="pop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#info1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info3">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info4">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info5">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info6">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info7">Item 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="info" id="info1"></div>
<div class="info" id="info2"></div>
<div class="info" id="info3"></div>
<div class="info" id="info4"></div>
<div class="info" id="info5"></div>
<div class="info" id="info6"></div>
<div class="info" id="info7"></div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
.info {
    /* hides by default */
    display: none;
}

.info:target {
    /* shows when targeted */
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nJm5J/1/).    ​

Incidentally, quoting attributes is optional (though if it's an attribute that contains white-space it *must* be quoted), but *if* you quote you must have a quote at *both* ends of the value you're quoting: `<div id="info-1></div>` is *not* valid HTML (since the string isn't closed until the next line at the *beginning* of the next attribute); use: `<div id="info-1"></div>`.

And, further, your posted jQuery:

```
$(function(){
     $('pop a').hover(function(){
          $('#info-1').show();
     },function(){
          $('#info-1').hide();
     });
});
```

This can't work, because:

1. the selector won't match any elements, you're trying to target an `a` element inside of a `pop` element (which, obviously, doesn't exist). What you need to do is preface the `id` with a `#` (as you do in the next line, so I'm assuming a typo there), to give: `$('#pop a')`. But,
2. there are no `a` elements in the `#pop` element, therefore no events will be, or can be, bound.

If you need to use that form, however, then a couple of adaptations can make it work:

```
$(function(){
     $('#pop li').hover(function(){
          $('#info-' + $(this).text().match(/(\d+)/)).show();
     },function(){
          $('#info-' + $(this).text().match(/(\d+)/)).hide();
     });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nJm5J/6/).

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`match()`](http://api.jquery.com/match/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: +1, How on earth did you compile a list of references that fast!?

Comment: Asad, that's because he is a ninja. Also, I prefer this method to the one with the data-popup, although you have to make sure you keep you things well ordered.

Comment: I...um, practice? And, in all honesty, it's not hard with jQuery references since it's *always* a predictable URL: `'http://api.jquery.com/' + methodName + '/'` You should see the failed Google-fu when it comes to reliable plain-ol' JavaScript references, though. *sigh* I do wish the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) would put together a similarly predictable (and *obvious*) reference. =)

Comment: @David Thomas I enjoy both of your ideas, but I believe the second one is not limited to the click event if you modify your selector to `$( $(this).children("a").attr("href") )`http://jsfiddle.net/nJm5J/2/.

Comment: And I suppose for the sake of keeping `hover`s on `a`s, you could change the hover function to look at the `a`s instead. http://jsfiddle.net/nJm5J/3/

Comment: @Douglas: the second example relies purely on CSS, so it's *definitely* limited to `click` events, since there's no way to target the `.info` elements from the `a` elements (at least, [not *yet*](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) there isn't).

Comment: My mistake; misread it. My jsFiddle, then, is simply an alternative way to use JavaScript to accomplish the same thing you already did haha.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
$(function(){
  $('#pop li').hover(function(){
     $('#info-'+$(this).index()+1).show();
  },function(){
     $('#info-'+$(this).index()+1).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample http://fiddle.jshell.net/7QmR5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pop">
    <ul>
        <li id="li1">Item 1</li>
        <li id="li2">Item 2</li>
        <li id="li3">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="info-1" style="display:none;">info 1</div>
<div id="info-2" style="display:none;">info 2</div>
<div id="info-3" style="display:none;">info 3</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#pop li').hover(function(){
        $('#info-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('li','')).show();
    },function(){
        $('#info-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('li','')).hide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got an easier solution:

CSS

```
#info-1{
    display:none;
}
ul > li:hover #info-1 {
    display:block;
}
```

giving the li elements an id will make it easier to select them using CSS unless you want to use pseudo I believe it's called.

Or the jQuery if needed:

```
$('li:eq[0]','#pop').hover(function(){
    $('info-1').show();
});
```

Comment: You realise your CSS version won't work, because the `div` elements aren't inside of the `li` elements. And the jQuery will only *show* the element, it'll not hide them again. Plus, there's a syntax error, it should be: `li:eq(0)` (parentheses, not brackets). And, even corrected, the OP would need to set up separate event-handlers for *each* `li` element. Then there's the context, which will *work*, yes, but why do that when it's easier to use `$('#pop li')` which doesn't use `find()` (internally) and instead uses, I think, the browser's `querySelectorAll()` to speed things up..?

Comment: @DavidThomas My bad I missed the sytax error. Using the selector $('#pop li') will be triggered on each hover of each <li> element. I determined that the quizzer wanted a unique selector for each <li> element within the <ul>. 
(eg: li:eq(0) -> show #info-1, li:eq(1) - > show #info-2).
And I never knew that the CSS selector wouldn't work I presumed it would as I didn't ask to find the child element '>'. How would you show the element #info-1 using ONLY CSS?